# How to call generated variables between modules in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am now working on a Python algorithm. I have generated a string called `raw_constraint` in `def constraint()` like:

```
def constraint():
    val=4
    ind=[]
    for i in range(1,7):
        for j in range(val,val+i):
            val = val+1
            ind.append(j)
            if(i < 6):
                boundNode.insert(j, 'x%d' % (j-(2*i+1)))
            raw_constraint = str(boundNode[j]) + " + " + str(boundNode[j-(2*(i+1))]) + " <= " + str(boundNode[(j-(2*(i+1))+i)] ) + " + " + str(boundNode[(j-(2*(i+1))+i)+1])
```

I would like to do a more operation on `raw_constraint`  in another module called `constraintBuild()`. I am now wondering how to call `raw_constraint` in a `def` called `constraintBuild()`.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming here that when you say "module" you mean "function".) You would either need to make it a global variable that both functions can access or have `constraint` return it to the caller and then pass it into `constraintBuild` as an argument.

Example:

```
raw_constraint = ''

def constraint():
    global raw_constraint
    # Your code

def constraintBuild():
    global raw_constraint
    # Your code
```

Or

```
def constraint():
    # Your code
    return raw_constraint

def constraintBuild(raw_constraint):
    # Your code

# Outer code
raw_constraint = constraint()
constraintBuild(raw_constraint)
```

The latter is generally preferred as global variables should be avoided where possible.

Comment: I tried the second approach, It works but not in the way I want. `print(raw_constraint)` in `constraintBuild(raw_constraint)` can only display 1 of them. I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Each time through the loop in the original code you assign a completely new value to `raw_constraint`, replacing the old one. Possibly you wanted to use a list that you would append each value to?

Comment: It might work but I'm afraid it'll be on the contrary way of my direction. I am going to split the string and rearrange them in `constraintBuild()`.